# Hbase Bulk load - Map Reduce job failing

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, bulk-load

I have map reduce job for hbase bulk load. Job is converting data into Hfiles and loading into hbase but after certain map % job is failing. Below is the exception that I am getting.

```
Error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/mapr/local/tm4/mapred/nodeManager/spill/job_1433110149357_0005/attempt_1433110149357_0005_m_000000_0/spill83.out.index
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.open(RawLocalFileSystem.java:198)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:800)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SecureIOUtils.openFSDataInputStream(SecureIOUtils.java:156)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SpillRecord.<init>(SpillRecord.java:74)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRFsOutputBuffer.mergeParts(MapRFsOutputBuffer.java:1382)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRFsOutputBuffer.flush(MapRFsOutputBuffer.java:1627)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.close(MapTask.java:709)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:779)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:345)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1566)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163)
```

Only thing that i noticed in job that for small set of data it is working fine but as data grows job starts failing.

Let me know if anyone has faced this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in MapR. I got reply on MapR forum. If someone is facing similar issue then refere below link.

http://answers.mapr.com/questions/163440/hbase-bulk-load-map-reduce-job-failing-on-mapr.html